# Forcing dark or light mode laravel nova 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, darkmode

I am working on a new CRM project, and I have found this in the documentation: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/installation.html#disabling-nova-s-theme-switcher which will remove the toggle button but will default the page to the OS setting. My question is is there a way to lock this so that regardless of OS setting its always one or the other?

Answer (score 7):

The other solutions work only once you are logged in.

To make it work both on login/forgot-password as well as logged-in screens follow these steps:

1. Create a file named `theme.js` in your public folder with the following content:

```
//public/theme.js

// Nova uses localStorage for the theme so we have to set theme to 'light'
localStorage.setItem("novaTheme", "light");
```

2. Create a `meta.blade.php` file which includes the JS file in the header of all pages:

```
//resources/views/vendor/nova/partials/meta.blade.php

<script src="{{asset('theme.js')}}"></script>
```

3. (optional) Edit `NovaServiceProvider.php` to disable theme switcher

```
//app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php

public function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    Nova::withoutThemeSwitcher(); 
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I achieved this by including a script in the Nova boot method which forces the light theme.

Boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Nova::remoteScript(asset('<dir/file>.js')); // this will include the script
    Nova::withoutThemeSwitcher(); // this method disables the theme switcher
}
```

Javascript code:

```
localStorage.setItem("novaTheme","light"); // set theme to 'light' in localStorage
document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark"); // remove the dark class
```

Comment: Noticed this doesn't work for the login page?

Comment: @Grant I added an answer that includes login page